# .NET: Message Queue vs directly inserting into MongoDB

Tags: .net, mongodb, message-queue

I have the following use case: a web application (actually the client's browser) periodically sends trackings / pings to the web server (via XHR, JSON). I am storing these tracks inside a MongoDB collection with a four-property-index. Obviously this collection will grow very fast.

I have three options in mind:

1. Just process the the JSON message and insert into MongoDB.
2. Get the
   JSON message and spawn a background task to insert into MongoDB
3. Process the JSON message and put a message on a queue (RabbitMQ?!)
   and then let the queue consumer insert into MongoDB.

Which one will perform best in a large internet scale use case? I think that 2-3) will have a severe overhead and therefore will be slower in development mode but I can't predict if 2-3) really will scale better. Since there will be lots of rows and there is a huge index I would say that inserting into the MOngoDB collection will be quite slow if a certain limit is reached.

Background information: it is not crucial that the processing of every message/tracking is guaranteed and if the server goes down it's ok if the data is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion - go with #1. Singleton inserts into MongoDB are extremely fast.  There is no need for a queue or back-end process. Also, based on you lack of strict data persistence, if your MongoDB is in a replica set, you can also connect without SafeMode turned on to keep the overhead at a minimum.

Some background reading - the folks at Boxed Ice even [replaced their RabbitMQ implementation](http://blog.serverdensity.com/2011/09/28/replacing-rabbitmq-with-mongodb/) with MongoDB.

Comment: Yeah ... that was my assumption too. Just wanted to have 2nd view on my problem.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view if your application will suffer very high overhead
and will need to scale I'd go for the option #3 which has the following advantages:

1. Since it is an asynchronous approach the performance will be better.
2. Is a more mature and advanced solution which allows to scale (eases to build distributed architectures)
3. Is more suitable for supporting overhead (take into account that RabbitMQ is written in Erlang  which one of its strengths is concurrency). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)
4. RabbitMQ is a proven performer an allows non-durable queues. This means that messages are not persisted and are lost when the server is stopped.

Of course this approach adds complexity to the development since more control is required (error handling, etc.)